# Two fields in Solspace Freeform - either one or the other must be filled out. Is it possible?

Tags: solspace-freeform, forms, solspace

I am building a form using Solspace Freeform, and we have two fields for telephone numbers - one for landline and one for mobile/cell.

Is it possible for me to make one or other of these fields required? I.E. If the user fills out landline but not mobile the form will submit, if the user fills out mobile but not landline the form will submit, but if the user doesn't fill out either then the form will return an error?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to solve with Jquery with depend function like so

```
$(".selector").validate({
    rules: {
        contact: {
            required: true,
        email: {
                depends: function(element) {
                     return ($('#theRequiredField').val() == '';
                }
        }
     }
}
```

SOURCE: http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#toptions
search " depends:"

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way within Freeform to set the `required=""` feature dynamically or to control the requirement of one field based on the value of another. Once values are set in the `required=""` parameter (or in the Composer editor), they can't be changed. The above solution is what we would suggest instead, and requires javascript/jQuery and a validation script.